# CHARINDEX not able to retrieve index in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, charindex

If we have a query as shown below, where the `CHARINDEX` is supposed to find the index of string in a given column, but the result is not as expected. Is there any other way to retrieve the index?

```
SELECT t.*, CHARINDEX('text', CAST([col] AS varchar)) AS [out]
FROM (
    SELECT CAST([col] AS NVARCHAR(4000)) AS [col] 
    FROM (
         VALUES ('"http:\/\/xxxxx.share.com\/text"'),
                ('random content in string :\/\\//\ / text \\\''''''')
    ) AS t0([col])
) t
```

the result is

```
col                                                 |  out
"http:\/\/xxxxx.share.com\/text"                    |    0
random content in string :\/\\//\ / text \\\''''''  |    0
```

But if I expect the output to be like

```
col                                                 |  out
"http:\/\/xxxxx.share.com\/text"                    |   28
random content in string :\/\\//\ / text \\\''''''  |   36
```

As the **text** char is in 28/36 in the rows respectively, how do we fetch the index position in this case?

Comment: `CAST([col] AS varchar))` needs to be `CAST([col] AS varchar(max)))` - you must always specify the length of a `varchar` or `nvarchar`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is almost a typo, and you are casting to `VARCHAR`, which may not be the appropriate length to actually fit all your data.  Just cast to a length long enough to accommodate your data, and your query should work:

```sql
SELECT t.*, CHARINDEX('text', CAST([col] AS varchar(255))) AS [out]  -- change is here
FROM (
    SELECT CAST([col] AS NVARCHAR(4000)) AS [col] 
    FROM (
         VALUES ('"http:\/\/xxxxx.share.com\/text"'),
                ('random content in string :\/\\//\ / text \\\''''''')
    ) AS t0([col])
) t
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `CAST` Function in your Query.

There is no need for Converting the Data type to `VARCHAR` here. Because it is already Converted into `NVARCHAR(4000)` in the below select Statement.

If you need so the use `CAST([col] AS varchar(max)))` instead of `CAST([col] AS varchar))`.

```
SELECT t.*, CHARINDEX('text', [col] ) AS [out]
FROM (
SELECT CAST([col] AS NVARCHAR(4000)) AS [col] 
FROM (
     VALUES ('"http:\/\/xxxxx.share.com\/text"'),
            ('random content in string :\/\\//\ /text \\\''''''')
) AS t0([col])
) t
```